Matrix Multiplication and Diagonal Scaling: Clarification on Operations
Let $ A $ be an $ n \times n $ matrix and $ D $ a diagonal matrix of the form
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We also define the matrix $ P $ as
$$
P = [\mathbf{v}_1 \, \mathbf{v}_2 \, \ldots \, \mathbf{v}_n],
$$
where $ \mathbf{v}_i $ are column vectors.
Is it true that the following equalities hold?
1.
$$
AP = A[\mathbf{v}_1 \, \mathbf{v}_2 \, \ldots \, \mathbf{v}_n] = [A \mathbf{v}_1 \, A \mathbf{v}_2 \, \ldots \, A \mathbf{v}_n]
$$
2.
$$
PD = P \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n
\end{bmatrix} = [d_1 \mathbf{v}_1 \, d_2 \mathbf{v}_2 \, \ldots \, d_n \mathbf{v}_n] \quad ?
$$
Any insight or clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

For the 1st, see the following for intuition (the algebraic proof can follow):
$\displaystyle AP = \sum_{i=1}^n A[\mathbf{0}, ..., \mathbf{v}_i, ... , \mathbf{0}] = \sum_{i=1}^n [\mathbf{0}, ..., A\mathbf{v}_i, ... , \mathbf{0}] = [A\mathbf{v_1}, ..., A\mathbf{v_n}]$
For the 2nd one, let $M = PD$ and $M_{ij}$ be the entries of $M$. Then:
$M_{ij} = \sum_{k} P_{ik}D_{kj} = 0 + P_{ij}d_j = P_{ij}d_j$.
Thus, $M$ indeed becomes the "scaled" version of $P$, as the $j$th column of $M$, $M_j$ is:
$M_j = d_jP_j = d_j\mathbf{v_j}$
Then, you yield your desired result. I hope this has been helpful.
